# Storing formatted HTML text in database

Tags: mysql, security, web, server-side-scripting

I am interested in allowing users to "share" information on my website, say something similar to a bulletin board concept.  This is something I've never done before because I know that it could introduce security issues.

I'll likely be using ColdFusion as my scripting language.  I'm also familiar with PHP, but am leaning towards CF because of its built-in RichText control.  The database back-end will either be MySql or SQLServer.

And so, my question boils down to this:  What are the specific security issues and how do I screen user input for them?  Does the method of SQL storage have any barring (say VARCHAR vs BLOB)?

Comment: HTML doesn't have any special meaning for the database engine. The risk is, of course, whatever you do with it once you retrieve it.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm kind of looking for a heads up on some of the "gotchas" - some of the specific things I should be screening for once a user submits their information to the server.  I'll likely be implementing a CAPTCHA system to guard against bots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: Related reading http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually use a CMS for the primary pages of our site, and the heart of it uses a database vs actual files on the system. So for most of the content on our site, we actually have HTML which is being retrieved from a database.

For example

> `blurb.body` will equal something like `'<p>This is a body paragraph</p>'`

Then one thing we seem to run into sometimes is a character encoding error. It seems like if someone copies some text into the CMS with a " ' " or something, there isn't anything that will convert it automatically to a '.

But yes, you should be able to do it. Just make sure whatever filtering you do going into the database is reversed correctly on its way out.

Comment: Do you have any tips on security - like preventing cross-site scripting or other attempts to introduce malicious code when that information is displayed to the end user?

Comment: @MichaelBuckman are the webpages full-featured and in need of scripts? If not, deactivate / remove all script-tags.

Comment: How do you deal with the situation in which someone includes HTML tags in their text (e.g. in the answer immediately above: "<p>This is..."? How do you prevent confusion between their intended inclusion of tags in the TEXT of their answer, and your own formatting tags? Do you escape their HTML entities?

Comment: My impression is that the 4 core HTML entities always need to be encoded so as to differentiate user-entered tags from the true formatting tags. See e.g. the mandatory encoding in TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding. At that location it is said: "...The base entities < > & ' and " will always be entity encoded into their named equivalents. Though ' and " will only be encoded within attribute values and < > will only be encoded within text nodes. This is correct according too the HTML and XML specs...."